# Exporting HTML canvas from inside of Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm writing a Chrome extension where a canvas is modified, and I want to have the option to save the canvas data as an image. Is there any way for me (using JavaScript) to save directly to the file system (ideal) or at least prompt the user with a download menu so they can save it themselves?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to do this except for these ideas:

- Online backend written in PHP or something
- An `iframe` to show the online website which would have the canvas on it
- Tell the user to right click and save the canvas image